# Ember.js How to trigger button action pressing "enter"?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

how to trigger an action using enter key. I've previously tabed on the button so its "active". For inputs i could go *enter='actionName'* which does not work for buttons.

```
<div class="input-group">
    {{clickable-textfield value=value placeholder=inputPlaceholder}}

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" {{action 'manuallySelect'}}>
            <span class="icon-user"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The form should be wrapped in a `<form>` tag and you can use `on='submit'` in the action:

```
  <form {{action 'saveBook' book on='submit'}} class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      {{input value=book.title class='form-control'}}
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled={{book.isNotValid}}>Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" {{action 'cancelBookEdit' book}}>Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Source: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/library-app1 | http://yoember.com

Comment: Tried this before, does not work for some reason. :S Have 2 investigate tomorrow

Comment: the button type has to be submit, I think.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you'll more than likely need to create a component.

```
ember g component enterable-button
```

Then in the component file, you'll need to listen for a key event and check if they key pressed was the enter key.

```
// components/enterable-button.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'btn',
    keyPress(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.sendAction('enter');
        }
    }
});
```

Now in your template, you'll call the component like this:

```
{{#enterable-button class="btn-default" enter='manuallySelect'}}
  <span class="icon-user"></span>
{{/enterable-button}}
```

This *should* work, but I wasn't able to create a jsbin right now. It might require a little reworking.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it tomorrow.